# Build a nine-level word guessing game

Tags: code-golf, game

### The basics:

You'll need to provide a nine-level word guessing game in the fewest characters possible (in your language of choice).

### The metrics:

- Provide a word-list
  (one word per line, seperated by a
  newline) (e.g.
  `/usr/share/dict/words` or similar could do). It's fine to
  pipe a filename or the wordlist
  itself into your solution.
- Provide 9 levels with incrementing word length (words with 4 characters `->` 12 characters):

```
Level 1:  a random word from the wordlist containing 4 characters
Level 2:  a random word from the wordlist containing 5 characters
...                                                  ...
Level 8:  a random word from the wordlist containing 11 characters
Level 9:  a random word from the wordlist containing 12 characters
```

- In every level, obfuscate a randomly chosen word from the list (with a specific word length of course) and replace a certain number of characters by the asterisk (`*`). The *number* of characters to replace: `current_word_length / 3` (round down). Randomize *which* characters to replace.
- Let the player 'guess' the word (only one `try` per level), give feedback (`correct` or `wrong`) and give points accordingly. When correct, the player gains `number_of_obfuscated_characters * 10 points`.
- Print the current score at the end of each level.

### The format (& sample I/O):

Make sure you follow the following formatting scheme:

```
Level 1     # level header
=======     # 
g*ek        # obfuscated word
geek        # user input
correct     # guess validation
score: 10   # print score
            #  
Level 2
=======
l*nux
linux
correct
score: 20

Level 3
=======
ran**m
random
correct
score: 40

...

Level 9
=======
sem***act*ve
semiinactive
wrong
score: 90
```

### Winner:

Shortest solution (by code character count). Have fun golfing!

Comment: What is the solution to sem***act*ve, BTW?

Comment: @JoeZ. maybe `sem***act*ve` ==> `semelfactive`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Perl, 180 chars

```
@w=<>;for$n(4..12){@x=grep/^.{$n}$/,@w;$_=$w=$x[rand@x];vec($_,rand$n,8)=42while($==$n/3)>y/*//;print"Level @{[$n-3]}
=======
$_";say<>eq$w?($@+=$=)&& correct:wrong,"
score: $@0
"}
```

Ruby beating Perl?  That will not do! :-)

Like jsvnm's Ruby solution, but unlike Joel Berger's Perl code, this script takes the filename of a word list as a command line parameter.  That is, you should run it like this:

```
perl -M5.010 guessword.pl /usr/share/dict/words
```

Here's a de-golfed version:

```
@w = <>;
for $n (4..12) {
    @x = grep /^.{$n}$/, @w;
    $_ = $w = $x[rand@x];
    vec($_, rand $n, 8) = 42 while ($= = $n/3) > y/\*//;
    print "Level @{[ $n-3 ]}\n=======\n$_";
    say <> eq $w ? ($@ += $=) && correct : wrong, "\nscore: $@0\n"; 
}
```

The statement `vec($_, rand $n, 8) = 42 while ($= = $n/3) > y/*//` contains a few interesting tricks.  First, 42 is the ASCII code of an asterisk; it turns out that using `vec` to modify single chars in a string is shorter than doing it with `substr`.  Second, the variable `$=` takes only integer values, so using it to store the number of hidden letters saves me an `int`.  Finally, `y/*//` is a short way to count the number of asterisks in a string using the transliteration operator.

Edit: Saved 7 chars by using `$@` to store the score divided by 10 and appending a zero to it during output (which, come to think of it, would've been shorter than the previous version even if I'd used a normal variable).

Edit 2: Turns out embedding literal newlines in the output strings saves a char over messing with `$,`.

Answer (score 5):

## Ruby (188)

takes the filename to read words from as argument.

```rb
q=*$<
s=0
4.upto(12){|n|o=''+w=q.grep(/^#{?.*n}$/).sample
[*0..n-1].sample(c=n/3).map{|i|o[i]=?*}
puts"Level #{n-3}",?=*7,o
puts STDIN.gets==w ?(s+=c;"correct"):"wrong","score: #{s}0",""}
```

Comment: Nice one (Ruby beating Perl, that's a not a familiar event in Code Golf ;-)

Comment: In my defense I didn't try that hard. Glad Ilmari Karonen had my back.

Answer (score 3):

## Bash, 350 chars

```
S=0
for L in {4..12}
do
echo -e Level $(($L-3))\\n=======
W=$(grep -E ^.{$L}$ /usr/share/dict/words|shuf|tail -1)
G=$W
while [ `sed 's/[^*]//g'<<<$G|wc -c` -le $(($L/3)) ]
do
P=$(bc<<<$RANDOM*$L/32767)
G=$(sed "s/\(.\{$P\}\)./\1*/"<<<$G)
done
echo $G
read U
if [ x$U == x$W ]
then
echo correct
S=$(($S+$L/3*10))
else
echo wrong
fi
echo score: $S
done
```

Comment: **No cheating!** It's 371 chars according to Notepad++.

Comment: @Nyuszika7H: including 21 \r chars, isn't it? This is for Unix, where a newline is a single linefeed char.

Comment: @ninjalj: Yeah, but keep in your mind that not everyone uses the Unix line break format. We have to be fair. http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/167/line-break-formats-and-character-numbers

Comment: @Nyuszika7H: If you can use it, then by all means you should in a code golf. If your language has two equivalent ways of doing something and one is shorter, do you use the longer because some people might not know the shorter one? As for line breaks, if you have a languages that *requires* CRLF, then you're out of luck, but I'm not aware of any such language.

Comment: Can't you almost always replace newlines w/ semicolons or spaces?

Comment: @barrycarter: you can replace them, but all of them take 1 character.

Comment: @ninjalj OK, I meant that it doesn't take 2, but maybe the discussion above already says that.

Comment: Totally unrelated, but I never knew you could use `<<<` for input to commands, that's pretty cool.

Answer (score 2):

## Perl: 266

```
@ARGV='/usr/share/dict/words';@w=<>;$"='';while($l<9){$o=1+int++$l/3;@s=grep{$l+4==length}@w;@g=split//,$t=$s[rand$#s+1];my%r;$r{rand$#g}++while keys%r<$o;$g[$_]='*'for keys%r;print"Level $l\n=======\n@g";print<>eq$t?do{$p+=$o*10;"Correct"}:"Wrong","\nScore: $p\n"}
```

or with a little more white space

```
@ARGV='/usr/share/dict/words';
@w=<>;
$"='';
while($l<9){
  $o=1+int++$l/3;
  @s=grep{$l+4==length}@w;
  @g=split//,$t=$s[rand$#s+1];
  my%r;
  $r{rand$#g}++while keys%r<$o;
  $g[$_]='*'for keys%r;
  print"Level $l\n=======\n@g";
  print<>eq$t?do{$p+=$o*10;"Correct"}:"Wrong","\nScore: $p\n"
}
```

and I think with a little work it could get even better!

Answer (score 2):

### R, 363 chars

```
w=tolower(scan("/usr/share/dict/words",what="c"));l=nchar(w);score=0;for(i in 1:9){mw=sample(w[l==i+3],1);cat("Level",i,"\n=======\n",replace(strsplit(mw,"")[[1]],sample(nchar(mw),floor(nchar(mw)/3)),"*"),"\n");v=scan(what="c",n=1,quiet=T);if(length(v)!=0&&v==mw){score=score+10*floor(nchar(mw)/3);cat("correct\n")} else cat("wrong\n");cat("score:",score,"\n\n")}
```

Answer (score 2):

## Python 335

I know I'm a bit late to the party, but python's not represented, so I figured what the heck:

```
import sys
import random
D=open(sys.argv[1]).read().split()
random.shuffle(D)
z=0
for L in range(1,10):
 M=L+3;N=M/3;w=[c for c in D if len(c)==M][0];U=list(w)
 for i in[random.randint(0,M-1)for i in range(N)]:U[i]='*'
 print"\nLevel %d\n=======\n"%L+''.join(U);k=raw_input()==w;z+=[0,N*10][k];print["wrong","correct"][k]+"\nscore:",z
```

And semi-ungolfed:

```
import sys
import random
words = open(sys.argv[1]).read().split()
random.shuffle(words)
score=0
for L in range(1,10):
   M=L+3
   N=M/3
   w=[c for c in words if len(c)==M][0]
   obfus=list(w)
   for i in [random.randint(0,M-1) for i in range(N)]: obfus[i]='*'
   obfus=''.join(obfus)
   print"\nLevel %d\n=======\n"%L+obfus
   correct=raw_input()==w
   score+=[0,N*10][correct]
   print["wrong","correct"][correct]+"\nscore:",score
```

Answer (score 2):

## K, 198

Assumes a dictionary d in the current working directory.

```
{O:{@[x;(-_c%3)?c:#x;:;"*"]}',/W:{1?x@&y=#:'x}[_0:`d]'4+!9;i:1+S:0;while[#O;-1"Level ",$i;-1"=======";-1@*O;$[(**W)~0:0;[-1"correct";S+:10*+/"*"=*O];-1"wrong"];-1"score: ",$S;-1"";W:1_W;O:1_O;i+:1]}
```

Ungolfed:

```
{
        /W = wordlist; O = obfuscated
        O:{@[x;(-_c%3)?c:#x;:;"*"]}',/W:{1?x@&y=#:'x}[_0:`d]'4+!9;     
        i:1+S:0;                            
        while[#O;
                -1"Level ",$i;
                -1"=======";
                -1@*O;
                $[(**W)~0:0;              /Read user input and compare to the first word
                        [-1"correct";
                        S+:10*+/"*"=*O];  /if correct, increment score
                        -1"wrong"];
                -1"score: ",$S;
                -1"";
                W:1_W;                    /knock one off the top of both word lists
                O:1_O;
                i+:1]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 3.8 (pre-release)](https://docs.python.org/3.8/), 283 bytes

```python
from random import*
def f(w,s=0):
 for i in range(4,13):W=choice([t for t in w if len(t)==i]);C=sample([*range(i)],T:=i//3);print(f'''Level {i-3}
=======
'''+''.join(I in C and'*'or c for I,c in enumerate(W)));print(['wrong','correct'][(Z:=input()==W)]+f'\nscore: {(s:=s+Z*10*T)}\n')
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NY4xa8MwEIV3/wptJ9lqk@AOxUFTpkDHgCGOB6NIyRX7JGSlpoT8dldO6C0H77577/nfeHVUfvowzza4gYWOzmnh4F2IeXY2llk@yVGtRZUx6wJDhrRgF8M/5KYUVa301aE2vIlPIC7AxNCy3hCPQilsxXanxm7wfaLy1zOKVh4qhatVKbY@IEVuAeDL/Jie3fGtfGTqNVmSC4D3b4fE94v7jqWakENK08/MvdSLbug2mNBFw2sh/l0bmIKjC0jQLgSjI7QNP6Zk8rfIU71atIWFE43pbip252OlxuKYb9b5QTxOBGKe/wA)

I'm on Windows so it's hard to test. But there is a version [here](https://onlinegdb.com/wxsp5BHMF) on a different interpreter site that uses a list of words compiled from [here](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/dwyl/english-words/master/words.txt). (albeit only about 8000 words).